# MSSQL Compare two tables row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying compare the results of two select statements row by row.
So for example the table looks like the following:

```
GUID | NUMBER (auto inc) | VERSION (timestamp) | Name
A    | 4                 | 1                   | Robert
B    | 9                 | 2                   | John
C    | 14                | 3                   | Magret
```

Now the selects look like

```
select guid from table order by number;
select guid from table order by version;
```

Now the tables should be compared row by row, if the GUIDs are the same in both selects at the same line. If so, return true, else false.

edit:
The goal is to detect a change of the columns GUID and NAME. The column NUMBER is an auto increment value, that only is increased when the entry is created. The VERSION is a timestamp, that changes every time the entry has been updated. Now it is the goal the compare both select queries from above to determine a change it the table, because if the order of the entries is different then a change has occurred.

Thanks,
shirocko

Comment: One more time, what are you trying to achieve - and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I changed the description above. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if all rows are ordered the same with the two columns, then:

```
select (case when count(*) = sum(case when rnk_1 = rnk2 then 1 else 0 end)
             then 'All Same'
             else 'Different'
        end)
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by number) as rnk_1,
             rank() over (order by version) as rnk_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.